# MATLAB boxplot XTickLabel with subscripts

Tags: matlab, latex, boxplot, subscript

```
boxplot(rand(10,2))                     
set(gca,'XTick',(1:2))
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'A_{a}','B_{b}'})  %a and b should be subscripts
```

Does not plot a and b as subscripts as it is suppose to do. Any suggestion on how to make subscripts for XTickLabel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK subscripts are not possible in XTickLabel or YTickLabel until R2014a. In earlier versions the labels will just show as an underscore because they are not displayed in `text` objects so don't support the latex interpreter.

In R2014a plot labels had 'tex' functionality added, so all versions from then on <strike>will</strike> should display correctly. Not sure why it doesn't appear to work for you in R2015a.

---

From R2014b, there is also a 'latex' interpreter which gives much more functionality. To enable this you would call:

```
set(gca,'TickLabelInterpreter','latex');
```

And format your tick labels as (note the `$$`):

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'$$A_{a}$$','$$B_{b}$$'});
```

---

There is a answer on the MATLAB community [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102053-how-can-i-make-the-xtick-and-ytick-labels-of-my-axes-utilize-the-latex-fonts-in-matlab-8-1-r2013a) which explains a work around. However this doesn't actually add latex to the plot labels. Instead it manually adds `text` objects to the plot with latex set as the interpreter.

Comment: Using R2015a, the above code still does not work.How to make this code work with R2015a?

Comment: @BERKO Does ```set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'A_a','B_b'})``` display correctly? I don't have R2015a, so can't test.

Comment: @BERKO You may also have to call ```set(gca,'TickLabelInterpreter','latex')``` and wrap the strings in ```$$```, e.g. ```set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'$$A_a$$','$$B_b$$'})```